Am I correctly applying repeated integration by parts?
Say we have two compactly supported functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. I found myself computing
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\frac{\partial^{r}g}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}} & = f\frac{\partial^{r-1}g}{\partial x^{\alpha_2}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}} - 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}}\frac{\partial^{r-1}g}{\partial x^{\alpha_2}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}}\\
& \ \ \vdots\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{r}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_k}}\frac{\partial^{r-k}g}{\partial x^{\alpha_{k+1}}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}}
+ (-1)^r\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\partial^{r}f}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}}g
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where each expression $\partial_{\alpha_i}\cdots\partial_{\alpha_j}f$ (or $g$) outside the integral is evaluated from $x_j=-A$ to $x_j=A$ for some rectangle $[-A,A]^n$ containing the support of $f$ (or $g$). That is,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f\frac{\partial^{r}g}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}} + (-1)^{r+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\frac{\partial^{r}f}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}}g = \sum_{k=1}^{r}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_k}}\frac{\partial^{r-k}g}{\partial x^{\alpha_{k+1}}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_r}}.$$


Firstly, am I correctly applying repeated integration by parts?

Secondly, due to symmetry of second partial derivatives, the order of the $\alpha_i$ does not change the value of the LHS. With that in mind, it seems to me we can write the expression as
$$\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in\mathbb{S}_n}\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\partial^k f}{\partial x^{\alpha_{\sigma(1)}}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_{\sigma(k)}}}\frac{\partial^{r-k}g}{\partial x^{\alpha_{\sigma(k+1)}}\cdots\partial x^{\alpha_{\sigma(r)}}}$$
Is this correct?



If everything is smooth compactly supported (or even Schwartz functions) then $\int f\partial^{\alpha}g=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int (\partial^{\alpha}f)g$. There are no boundary terms. If you only want to “transfer” some of the derivatives then the formula is suitably modified.
